# Json in Postman Params

Tags: json, rest, post, https, postman

Is there a way to put a json Value in a Postman Param?

it seems that it's making the request to return "400-bad request", and that it won't accept json.

Want to put the following value in "Message":

{"default":"A message.","email":"A message for email.","email-json":"A message for email (JSON).","http":"A message for HTTP.","https":"A message for HTTPS.","sqs":"A message for Amazon SQS."}

is there a simple pattern to do this?

[What I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQyQZ.png)

Comment: Your question completely fails to tell why **where** you put that data in postman, or provide any debugging information about the server which might explain why it thinks the request is malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want to send a JSON data as a query in URL.

In this case, it is necessary to **encode** the data, otherwise you will receive a 400 error from the server.

You can do the encoding operation manually, but the logical and correct way is to use the **pre-request script** tab in the postman.

With the help of pre-request script and **JavaScript** language, you can get and encode the request params in a simple and automatic way.

Suppose we define a key named `Message` in the **Params** tab, whose value is a JSON as follows:
`{"default":"A message.","email":"A message for email.","email-json":"A message for email (JSON).","http":"A message for HTTP. ","https":"A message for HTTPS.","sqs":"A message for Amazon SQS."}`

Now by adding the code below in the pre-request script section, you can automatically receive the parameters and then encode them:

```js
// Get all query parameters
const queryParams = pm.request.url.query.all();

// Encode each query parameter value
queryParams.forEach((param) => {
    param.value = encodeURIComponent(param.value);

    pm.request.url.removeQueryParams(param.key);
    pm.request.url.addQueryParams(param);
});
```

This will send a request like this:

`Message=%7B%22default%22%3A%22A%20message.%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22A%20message%20for%20email.%22%2C%22email-json%22%3A%22A%20message%20for%20email%20(JSON).%22%2C%22http%22%3A%22A%20message%20for%20HTTP.%22%2C%22https%22%3A%22A%20message%20for%20HTTPS.%22%2C%22sqs%22%3A%22A%20message%20for%20Amazon%20SQS.%22%7D`

The server can easily receive and process this information.

To make sure everything is working properly, I made a simple server with nodejs and tested this code, everything seems to be fine.

You can see the example code of the server with nodejs in [this link](https://gist.github.com/HamidMolareza/bc276b2649c1cb5d5a654abbcb837bd3) and run it yourself to make sure everything is correct.

Comment: Thank! it worked, I didn't know that there is a limitation for complex data object on Postman query params, many thanks.